# How to disable onclick on an element that is positioned over my draggable div only when drag is initiated?

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have a master div that is draggable.

Within this div is a note div (`.noteDiv`) with a higher `z-index`. When the note is clicked, it opens up to be editable.

Whenever I click-drag and the cursor is on the note div, the note div opens up to be editable after the dragging is done.

How can I prevent the `onclick` action on the `.noteDiv` when I'm dragging?

To make my dialogDocs div draggable, I simply have: `jQuery("#dialogDocs").draggable({scroll:true});`

Thanks in advance

Here is what the html/php code looks like

`<div id="dialogDocs"><div id="topLeft" style="border:0;top:0;left:0;width:10px;height:10px;position:absolute;z-index:599;">
                <? WorkItem::drawWorkItemBoxes(array('scaleNotesMultiplier'=>$scaleNotesMultiplier));?>
            </div>
            <div id="dialogImage<?=$i+1?>Container" class="dialogImageContainer" processId="<?=$processId?>" style="width:<?=$scaledMediaWidth?>px;height:<?=$scaledMediaHeight?>px;">
                <div id="densitometerPopupDiv<?=$i+1?>"></div>
                <img id="dialogImage<?=$i+1?>" processId="<?=$processId?>" src="dialogImageStreamer.php<?=$queryString?>"/>
            </div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You could make another child div to be the handle, and use

```
jQuery("#masterDiv").draggable({scroll:true, handle: "#handle"});
```

Comment: Hey John. I added my code and cleared up some things within my question. #masterDiv you were referring to is actually #dialogDocs. Where exactly would you add a child div as the handle? I don't see how that would prevent the .noteDiv from opening inside of the topLeft div.

Comment: The handle div just needs to be a sibling of the noteDiv. When you set a handle for a draggable object, then it only drags if your initial click is on that handle element.

Comment: If you could make a jsfiddle, that would be helpful in understanding your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just a fyi on what I did to resolve this.

I set `#dialogDocs` as the master div to be dragged. Within `#dialogDocs` is `#topLeft` which houses the `.noteDiv`.

I simply had to write this

`jQuery('#dialogDocs').draggable({
            scroll:true,
            start:function(event,ui){
                jQuery("#dialogDocs .noteBox").each(function(){
            document.getElementById(jQuery(this).attr('id')).style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        });
            },
            stop:function(event,ui){
                jQuery("#dialogDocs .noteBox").each(function(){
            var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
            document.getElementById(id).style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
        });
            }
        });`

On start of the drag, I disable the ability to click any `.noteDiv`. On stop of the drag, I re-enable it.

Sorry if my question was not clear enough. Hopefully this helps someone in need.